# JSF and Browser Issues?

Tags: firefox, jsf, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I am using JSF 1.2 without tomahawk and other libraries. The JSF Applicatin works fine in IE7 but there are problems - input controls not enabled (for Firefox 3.0.3) and rendered and disabled attributes of commandButtons do not work in IE8. I am using simple javascript and css to do some validations and conditional displays at the client side. Are there any known issues while writing JSF Applications for different browsers? Any advice you could provide for these issues? Appreciate your help.

[JSF and Browser Thread in Sun Forum](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5344032)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was , I was using a DIV tag with position:absolute css attribute and that has made the firefox browsers (3.0 to 3.6) frozen. This was not due to the JSF Implementation.When i fixed those issues, It was all fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter browser specific issues, then there's most likely a bug in the generated or homegrown JavaScript or CSS used. All JSF does is generating and sending HTML/CSS/JS and all the webbrowser retrieve and understand is HTML/CSS/JS.

If you encounter a bug in the generated HTML/CSS/JS (which is very rare though), which is not fixed yet in the latest JSF implementation version, then best what you can do is to report it to the JSF impl boys. At least, Mojarra boys are known to prioritize client side issues very high. Last serious issue I recall with regard to Mojarra is a Safari/Webkit related [bug](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-691) with `document.forms[formname]`, but that's already been fixed over 2 years ago.

Coming back to problems specifically with `rendered`, `disabled` and `readonly` attributes: those are also often caused by not properly understanding the lifecycle of HTTP request/response (the request scope) and/or the JSF lifecycle (those attributes are also checked during apply request values) and/or the wall between client side and server side (you cannot change them with alone JavaScript without sending/handling as HTTP request parameter yourself). This is unrelated to webbrowsers.